# In JMeter when I try to pass the variable assigned with JSON extractor to the subsequent request null value is passed

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I do a POST request using Jmeter and I parse the JSON response using the JSON extractor. When i use the debug sampler I could see the  Variable is assigned with the value properly but that value goes as null in the subsequent request

[image: Json Extractor image]

[image]

Below is the request URL for the next sample /XXX/XXX/XXX/XX/${recordingjobid}
but this value recordingjobid is not substituted with the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only think of not proper placement of the JSON Extractor.

For example if you have it at the same level as several samplers - it will be run after every of them (including the [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler)) and each next one will be overwriting the value set by the previous one as [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) are local to the thread and don't allow duplicates.

So my expectation is that if you move the JSON Extractor to be a child of the request which returns the JSON - it should resolve your issue.

More information: [JMeter Scoping Rules - The Ultimate Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide)